# Breaking one row into multiple rows in R

Tags: r, dataset

I've been recently dealing with data like this:

```
abs bh12|bh56|bh77 ccc

bbs bh50|bh87 css
```

What I am trying to do is split every row containing more than one | separated value in second column to rows, where there is only one such value in each row. So output would be:

```
abs bh12 ccc
abs bh56 ccc
abs bh77 ccc
bbs bh50 css
bbs bh87 css
```

I've been fiddling around with loops, but I am sure there is a better way to do this, but I am afraid it is currently out of my reach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below assumes you have these values are stored in a `data.frame` called `df` with column names "a", "b", and "c". Using the `splitstackshape` library:

```
print(df)
    a              b   c
1: abs bh12|bh56|bh77 ccc
2: bbs      bh50|bh87 css

library(splitstackshape)
df2 <- cSplit(df, "b", "|", direction = "long")
print(df2)

    a    b   c
1: abs bh12 ccc
2: abs bh56 ccc
3: abs bh77 ccc
4: bbs bh50 css
5: bbs bh87 css
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of this neat function.

Comment: No problem! It really comes in handy. In cases where you want to break out to multiple columns instead of rows, you can use direction = "wide"!